# Google page answer not formatted correctly

Tags: bug, google

I have no idea if there is any way to change it on the SE side of things or if it's something only Google can change, but I'll add it here anyway.

I searched for *Java how many characters in a string* in Google, and Google helpfully decided to give me the answer of the first link (which was a SO question) right in the Google page:

[image: google result]

Which is good except for the first line: *vote 90 down vote accepted.* Which is weirdly formatted and doesn't even seem right (63 total votes) so is unhelpful and looks bad.

If it's possible that line should be removed, or possibly changed to *Accepted Answer* as that may be helpful.

Comment: I do this all the time and [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) stuff always formats perfectly -- perhaps it was that particular request?

Comment: What I mean to ask is, is it reproducible?

Comment: it is with that search, not sure with others, I've tried several other question titles, but it doesn't show the answer on Google like that question does, I'm not sure what determines when google will show it.

Comment: [Never mind, I reproduced it.](http://i.imgur.com/13f5zuh.png) Perhaps that question has some offending markdown

Comment: Links to [the SO answer in the screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1179996) and [the question it belongs to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have)

Comment: @cat it has html in it: `<sup>31</sup>` is that what you meant?

Comment: @Aequitas no, the question's formatting itself seems fine. However, that question is from back in 2009, when the layout and format of SO/SE was very different. I think google caches how those boxes are displayed for certain sites, so the box template that works for modern SE doesn't work for old SE.

Comment: As for "doesn't even seem right (63 total votes)" - it's the answer, which now have 92 score, so it was indeed 90 when Google last cached it. But agree it's  a bug - somewhere.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CO3tB.png

Comment: In cases like this, I would recommend clicking the Feedback link in the lower-right corner to tell Google about the problem.